# Редирект https.

Tags: apache, ssl, https, nginx

Добрый день. Подскажите решение

Есть сайт на котором установлен покупной SSL сертификат, при каждом обращении по http:// автоматом редиректит на https:// Мне нужно чтоб не было этого редиректа, если идёт обращение http:// - отдвал сайт без защищенного соединения, с https://  защищенное. Не могу найти инфу как это сделать. Все варианты приводят к зацикливанию редиректов.

Установлено на сервере: nginx + apache + comodo ssl

Конфиг nginx http://pastebin.com/K9Y8kh6i

Comment: покажите конфиг nginx

Comment: конфиг nginx тут http://images.besaba.com/nginx.conf

Comment: @trans, в данный момент сцылка не рабочая

Comment: Извиняюсь, фрихост какойто убогий выбрал для заливки файла. Перезалил конфиг сюда http://pastebin.com/K9Y8kh6i ip и домен изменён, сам конфиг полный, как есть

Comment: еще может быть такая фигня, что сам сайт (имею ввиду движок сайта) редиректит на https... что за движок?

Comment: движок самопал, нет там таких плюшек - это пара nginx + apache мудрят

Answer (score 2):

В конфиге nginx разнесите обработку http и https в разные директивы server.

Comment: Спасибо, пробовал - все равно редирект в циклы уходит. Редиректы на уровне .htaccess сервер не слышит, какие только регулярки туда не ставил, а коррекция nginx - циклы редиретов.

Comment: покажите обновлённый конфиг nginx

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess, это можно сделать таким образом:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*):SSL$   https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*):NOSSL$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: @Deonis, уберите, в конфиге nginx так написать нельзя.

Comment: @kolpak, ну, я как бы написал, что по поводу nginx  - это только моё предположение. Но хорошо, уберу эту часть, чтоб не мозолило глаз. 
И повторюсь, что я не сталкивался с такой задачей, но возможно надо создать две директивы server.

    # SSL
    server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name site.com;
    
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/certs/site.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certs/site.key;
    }
    
    # Не SSL
    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name site.com;
    
        rewrite (.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
    }

Comment: @Deonis, теперь правильнее. Хотя, рекомендуют писать так:

rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent

но топикстартер спрашивал совсем о другом, "Мне нужно чтоб не было этого редиректа, если идёт обращение http:// - отдвал сайт без защищенного соединения", поэтому ждём конфиг фронтенда.

Comment: конфиг тут http://pastebin.com/K9Y8kh6i